# Wrap SPAN around all numbers in a DIV

Tags: javascript, numbers, html

I am trying to wrap a span around all numbers in a div so I can style them accordingly.

I have searched for some javascript to do this with no luck on being able to target all the numbers within the div.

It will be for Bible verses that will be copied and pasted into a textarea. I would like to style all of the numbers within that. Similar to how this site does here: http://marshill.com/media/trial/trial-and-jesus#scripture

Under the "Scripture" tab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

```
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace( /\b(\d+)\b/g, '<span>$1</span>' );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ujA86/

Comment: Are there no numbers in scripture aside from verse number annotations? ;)

Comment: @amnotiam OP clearly asked: `I would like to style all of the numbers within that.`, this answer is perfectly acceptable under this request. I guess you could question OP about that. `;)`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Very true. Anyway, did a quick search (only using NKJV), and the only number symbol I could find as part of the actual text [was here](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+13:18&version=NKJV). The rest must be words. You're off the hook @Šime Vidas... for now. `;)`

Comment: @amnotiam I gave it a shot: http://jsfiddle.net/ujA86/2/ Notice how the number 666 is not wrapped.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Validation of numeric sequential order. Very nice!

Comment: @amnotiam I forgot that `replace()` accepts a callback function. This enabled me to significantly reduce the code size: http://jsfiddle.net/ujA86/6/ Code-golf version: http://jsfiddle.net/ujA86/4/

Comment: Looks good. For some reason a prefer `exec`, but you're right, it certainly does reduce the code.

Comment: how to avoid anything between angular brackets (<>) within string since <p> tag can have <a> tag inside which may have numbers in href attribute and possible color codes in other inline tags.